# supplying password to SFTP

Tags: passwords, sftp

I have a simple script where i need to connect to SFTP and put a file,below is the script.But I am getting a error message  showing "No such file or directory mgtest@100.45.5.27)".Can somebody help me on this.

```
#!/bin/sh
# sample automatic ftp script to dump a file
USER="mgtest"
PASSWORD="cald123"
HOST="100.45.5.27"
sftp -b $USER@$HOST << EOF
$PASSWORD
#cd test_path
put test_file.txt
quit
EOF
```

Execution Screen and error

```
$ sh -x sftp_test.sh
+ sh -x sftp_test.sh
+ USER=mgtest
+ PASSWORD=testpass
+ HOST=100.45.5.27
+ sftp -b mgtest@100.45.5.27
+ 0<<
testpass
#cd test_path
#put test_file.txt
quit
No such file or directory (mgtest@100.45.5.27).
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter -b expects a batchfile, not username and password. See the [docs for sftp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp)

Comment: Thanks for your response, how to give password within the script,I am new to sftp.